# Why is Eren's hardening ability needed for the Executioner From Hell?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm reasonably certain this makes zero sense whatsoever but just checking if I'm missing something...it's a gap that they lure titans into before dropping a log on the back of their neck to kill them. What does that have to do with Eren's ability? Why was it at all necessary to have the crystalline structure around that?

See picture [here](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Executioner_from_Hell_(Anime)?file=Executioner_from_Hell_%2528Anime%2529.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titans are immensely strong. The only thing that prevents civilization inside the walls being destroyed by regular titans prior to the arrival of the Collosal and Armoured Titan is the special construction of the Walls.

As you will know by now, the walls are

> made out of titans using the same hardening ability.

Without using Erin's hardening, and the crystalline structure is just a way of extending the hardening beyond his usual titan form body shape, the edges of the gap would be quickly destroyed and Titans free to rampage inside the next wall.